# Why does GET Details returns all Null and Delete Details returns "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." when using objects.filter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I built a rest framework in Django. When I do getAll, I get all the data from my database (no problem). The problem is when I do GET details and DELETE details. For the get and delete, I need to return and delete multiple objects (not just one and not all).
In my case the problem is using objects.filter(). When I try using objects.get(id=id), I have no problem

models.py:

```
class ProA(models.Model):
    var1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    var3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ProASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProA
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('proa-getAll/', views.getAll, name='proa_getAll'),
    path('proa-getOne/<str:var1>', views.getOneSet, name='proa_getOne'),
    path('proa-delete/<str:var1>', views.deleteOneSet, name='proa_delete'),
]
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAll(request):
    proas = ProA.objects.all()
    serializer = ProASerializer(ProA.objects.all(), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getOneSet(request, var1):
    proa = ProA.objects.filter(var1=var1)
    serializer = ProASerializer(proa, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteOneSet(request, var1):
    try:
        data = ProA.objects.filter(var1=var1)

    except data.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'The var1 value does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    data.delete()

    return Response({'message': 'Data was deleted successfully!'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

When I go to the getOneSet URL to get all the objects where var1=MS107, I get the following:

[image: GetOneSet]

When I go to the deleteOneSet URL to delete all the objects where var1=MS107, I get the following:

[image: delete one set]

I have tried many things, but no idea how to solve them. I am new to Django, so I hope I added all info needed.

Comment: when you try to reach the url via browser, you are aplying an GET (the same occur if you try to reach www.google.com)...instead, use DELETE button

Comment: Sorry, can you please be more specific? I do not understand

Comment: Also, when I click on delete button, I get: "message": "Data was deleted successfully!"
Even though var1 does not have the value I used. It should say 'The var1 value does not exist' according to my code. There must a problem with filter I guess

Comment: if you try to reach this url (127.0.0.1:8000/api/proa-delete/MS107) via browser (where in your first image is 127.0.0.1:8000/api...) you will apply an GET method...instead, go to the root of this project via url (maybe 127.0.0.1:8000/api ) and then reach delete url

Comment: my problem persists. Either I click on delete, get, whatever, it does not change.

Comment: no. It does not work. I would deeply appreciate if you can provide a more complete analysis to solve this. I have been struggling a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252913/discussion-between-magaren-and-ananvodo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try to apply this:

@api_view(['GET'])
def getOneSet(request, var1):
    proa = ProA.objects.filter(var1=var1)
    serializer = ProASerializer(proa, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteOneSet(request, var1):
    data = ProA.objects.filter(var1=var1)
    if data:
        data.delete()
        return Response({'message': 'Data was deleted successfully!'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
    return Response({'message': 'The var1 value does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```